# How to optimize RBF parameters $C,\gamma$ with KSVM method?

Tags: classification, svm, hyperparameter

I want to find the best choice of $C$ and $\gamma$ parameters for Radial Basis Function kernel.

I am using **kernlab** instead of **e1071** library. So how can i optimize RBF parameters $C$ and $\gamma$ with ksvm function?

Comment: This question is just a more specific version of this one. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310

Answer (score 2):

You can use Optunity for that purpose. This is a library of optimization algorithms for automated hyperparameter search.

You can find an example of using Optunity to optimize an SVM in e1707 [here](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/r/svm.html), mapping this to kernlab should be straightforward. All you need to do is specify box constraints (a lower and upper bound) on $C$ and $\gamma$ and a budget of function evaluation (i.e., how many ($C$, $\gamma$)-pairs can be tested.

Comment: I use R for svm classification, but i can not install Optiunity package. Thankyou Mr. Claesen

Comment: Excuse me Mr. Claesn, I didn't know that you are main contributor of Optunity package.
At last, the command
`install_github("claesenm/optunity/wrappers/R")` worked for me!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! If you run into any problems, please let us know via Github issues so we can solve them ASAP.